# How to make pure javascript live search method?

Tags: javascript, html, search

I have the current data

```
<data name="John" job="officer"></data>
<data name="Michael" job="teacher"></data>
<data name="Tommy" job="artist"></data
<data name="Arnold" job="doctor"></data>
```

and continues up to 100 lines.
How can I create a live search input form using only HTML and pure Javascript?

For example, if someone types something matching the `name` attribute and then clicks the button labeled **Show Job** a div element containing the name and job is shown like this:

```
Name: ...
Job: ...
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. You should post what you tried so far so you can get help effectively.

Comment: I guess you are looking for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you can do:

```js
let result = document.getElementById("result")
let name = document.getElementById("name")

name.onkeyup = () => {
  let data = document.querySelectorAll(`data[name="${name.value}"]`)
  if (data.length) {
    result.textContent = Array.from(data).map(i => `${name.value} is a ${i.getAttribute("job")}`).join(", another ")
  } else {
    result.textContent = `No "${name.value}" found`
  }
}
```

```html
<data name="John" job="officer"></data><data name="John" job="teacher"></data>
<data name="Michael" job="teacher"></data>
<data name="Tommy" job="artist"></data>
<data name="Arnold" job="doctor"></data>
<input id="name">
<div id="result"></div>
```

I'd prefer storing data as a JS object or using [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) as [`<data> tag`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/data) doesn't seems to have this role

---

note : the strings are built using [`template literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)